# General method for approaching functional equations

Tags: real-analysis, functions

Suppose there exists a continuous function satisfying the functional equation, $ f(g(x))=f((h(x))+ f_1(x)$.

Now the way I like to tackle this kind of problem is assuming $f(x)= \sum a_if(x)$. Where all $a_i$'s are real or complex number that may also depend on the choice of $x$.

This method works very well if all $g(x), h(x)$ and $f_1(x)$ are polynomial functions. This method becomes very tedious if any one of the given functions are given in form of quotients.

Say for example:

$$f(x)+f(\frac{x-1}{x})=1+x$$

How to solve this kind of problem efficiently? Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $h(x) = \frac{x-1}x$.
Then $h^2(x) = \frac1{1-x}$ and $h^3(x) =  x$.

Our relation is that $f(t)+f(h(t)) = 1+ t$.
We hence have

$$\left\{
\begin{array}{cccccccl}
f(x)&+&f\left(\frac{x-1}x\right)& =& 1& +& x&\quad\quad\quad(1)\\
f\left(\frac{x-1}x\right)& +& f\left(\frac1{1-x}\right)& =& 1& +& \frac{x-1}x&\quad\quad\quad(2)\\
f\left(\frac{1}{1-x}\right)& +& f\left(x\right)& =& 1& +& \frac1{1-x}&\quad\quad\quad(3)\\
\end{array}\right.$$

Via $(1)-(2)+(3)$ we find that

$$2f(x) = 1 + x - \frac{x-1}x +\frac1{1-x},$$

that is,

\begin{align}
f(x)
&=
\frac12 \left(x + \frac1x + \frac1{1-x}\right)
\\&=
\frac{1+x^2-x^3}{2(1-x)x}
\end{align}

---

I hope it's clear how the technique above can be easily generalized whenever $h^n(x) = x$ for some odd $n\geqslant 1$.
We would consider, in the obvious notation, the linear combination $(1) - (2) + (3) - \dots - (n-1) + (n)$.

On the other hand, if $h^n(x) = x$ for even $n$, this imposes a condition on the RHS of the relation $(1+t$ in our case$)$, which might help in identifying when no solution exists, but does not otherwise provide a solution *per se*.
This is a consequence of the fact that the square $n\times n$ matrix

$$
\pmatrix{
1&1&0&0&\dots&0&0\\
0&1&1&0&\dots&0&0\\
0&0&1&1&\dots&0&0\\
0&0&0&1&\dots&0&0\\
\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots&\vdots\\
0&0&0&0&\dots&1&1\\
1&0&0&0&\dots&0&1\\
}$$

is invertible when $n$ is odd, but not when $n$ is even.